# Did Yoda ever say "Powerful the dark side is"?

Tags: star-wars

For years I lived with the impression that I have heard that quote somewhere in the movies but I can't Google it so I am starting to think I am confused. Is there an instance where Yoda (or maybe another character) says that?

Comment: I can hear it too, I think it is in relation to the future being clouded. Or maybe when talking to Luke about the cave on Degobah?

Comment: "Powerful the dark side maybe, but not that powerful."

Comment: Perhaps “Powerful you have become, the dark side I sense in you.”

Comment: "*For my ally is the Force, and a powerful ally it is. Life creates it,*"

Comment: **"Luke:** *Vader... Is the dark side stronger?* **Yoda:** *No, no, no. Quicker, easier, more seductive.*

Comment: @CaptainCold "Powerful the dark side maybe, but not that powerful." - that might be the one, where is it from?

Comment: @Daishozen I can't find it though. It might also be from Yoda speaking to the Jedi council or something in the prequels... or it might not exist at all

Comment: "Hard to see, the dark side is" - Ep. 1

Comment: @CaptinCold I believe the "but not that powerful" line you're referring to is from the first episode of the Clone Wars cartoon. But the quote is "Strong you are with the dark side young one. But not that strong". Here's a link to the clip https://youtu.be/m4GLA1niZeE?t=68

Comment: I found two fan-fictions and a cartoon that say it. But no canon. https://regularshowfanon.fandom.com/wiki/All_Star_Team_Up and http://ultracondensedmovie.blogspot.com/2007/05/star-wars-v-empire-strikes-back.html https://www.vivtek.com/toonbots/toon20020623.html

Comment: Yes, maybe "Hard to see, the dark side is" combined with someone else's line--"If only you knew the power of the dark side" (or one of several similar quotes from Vader/Palpatine)?

Comment: You might be thinking of the dialog that happened when Luke asks Yoda "is the dark side stronger?" in the Empire Strikes Back

Comment: Is Yoda's favourite album "The Moon The Dark Side Of" by Floyd Pink? :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### The phrase you thought in scripts occur does not.

I looked for the phrase "dark side is" in all the scripts that can be downloaded from https://starwarssuperfans.wordpress.com/real-world-news/star-wars-scripts/ .

The words do occur a couple of times, but not in combination with "powerful". The only references are the ones already mentioned in comments.